# How to filter object inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to check condition inside array with single object.

```
let arr = [
  {
    name: "john",
    description: {
      height: 5.5,
      weight: 54,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "mary",
    description: {
      height: 5.8,
      weight: 65,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "smith",
    description: {
      height: 6.1,
      weight: 85,
    },
  },
];

let obj = {
  height: 5.8,
  weight: 65,
};
```

i want to compare the obj within the array and if its match one, i want to get the name.
for ex, obj is equal to marry. i want to print mary.
This is what i have tried.

```
let result = arr.filter((item) => item.description === obj )
console.log(result.name);
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: If you want to find the one for mary, why not `item.name === 'mary'`?

Comment: Otherwise generalized object equality is only true if the objects are the exact same objects in memory.  If they are not, `item.description === obj` will be false, even if the key value pairs of both objects match.

Comment: i know only the height and weight of the person. with that information i want to find the name.

Comment: `item.description.height === obj.height && item.description.weight === obj.weight`

Comment: i tried. did'nt worked

Comment: @Nijus can you share what u tried along these lines and didn't work

Comment: Keep in mind `filter()` is going to return an array.  So doing `.name` off of the array isn't going to work.  You'd have to use `[0]` before accessing the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a filter with the entries of the object and iterate all entries and check the values. Then map the names.

```js
let array = [{ name: "john", description: { height: 5.5, weight: 54 } }, { name: "mary", description: { height: 5.8, weight: 65 } }, { name: "smith", description: { height: 6.1, weight: 85 } }],
    object = { height: 5.8, weight: 65 },
    filters = Object.entries(object),
    result = array
        .filter(({ description }) => filters.every(([key, value]) => description[key] === value))
        .map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare the desired keys against each other, rather than comparing the objects, as object equality is based upon their memory addresses being the same.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    name: "john",
    description: {
      height: 5.5,
      weight: 54
    }
  },
  {
    name: "mary",
    description: {
      height: 5.8,
      weight: 65
    }
  },
  {
    name: "smith",
    description: {
      height: 6.1,
      weight: 85
    }
  }
];

let obj = {
  height: 5.8,
  weight: 65
};

console.log(
  arr.filter(item => item.description.height === obj.height && item.description.weight === obj.weight)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can narrow down the the property that you want to filter on like this

```
  let arr = [{
      name: "john",
      description: {
        height: 5.5,
        weight: 54
      }
    },
    {
      name: "mary",
      description: {
        height: 5.8,
        weight: 65
      }
    },
    {
      name: "smith",
      description: {
        height: 6.1,
        weight: 85
      }
    }
  ];

  let obj = {
    height: 5.8,
    weight: 65
  };

  const filtered = arr.filter(({ description }) => description.height === obj.height && description.weight === obj.weight);
  console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be using `Object.keys`.

```js
var arr = [ { name: "john", description: { height: 5.5, weight: 54, }, }, { name: "mary", description: { height: 5.8, weight: 65, }, }, { name: "smith", description: { height: 6.1, weight: 85, }}];

var obj = { height: 5.8, weight: 65 };

var result = arr.filter(({description})=>Object.keys(description).every(k=>description[k]==obj[k])).map(({name})=>name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for the failure of filter filter condition is due to the comparison between objects being attempted.

Comparison of objects can be done by using a helper function.

**Here is the working exmaple:**

```
// array-filter-demo.js
let arr = [
    { name: "john", description: { height: 5.5, weight: 54 } },
    { name: "mary", description: { height: 5.8, weight: 65 } },
    { name: "smith",description: { height: 6.1, weight: 85 } }
  ]

let obj = { height: 5.8, weight: 65 }

// Helper function to compare objects
function matching(a, b) {
   return ( a.height === b.height && a.weight === b.weight)
}

// Call the helper function inside filter
const result = arr.filter(item => (matching(item.description, obj)))
console.log(result)
```

**Output:**

```
$ node array-filter-demo.js 

[ { name: 'mary', description: { height: 5.8, weight: 65 } } ]
```